# Some tags are not read with read_html

Tags: html, r, rvest

I used read_html to read this website (Korean portal site for stock trading market) "https://finance.naver.com/sise/etf.nhn"
When I saw the elements of the webpage, I see a table, and tags such as tbody, tr, td, a under the table. 
However, read_html does not read these tags but properly. I checked it with xml_structure. There is only tbody with an ID, but nothing else.

I do not know other way to read website but read_html.

```
url <- "https://finance.naver.com/sise/etf.nhn"

temp <- url %>%
  read_html(encoding="iso-8859-1") %>%
  xml_find_all(., "//td[@class = 'ctg']") %>%
  as_list()
```

This did not give me anything, so I double-checked it with xml_structure.

```
xml_structure(read_html(url, encoding="iso-8859-1"))
```

And it gives the following:
There should be lots of "tr"s and "td"s under the "tbody", but nothing.

```
        <table [summary, class, cellspacing, cellpadding]>
          <caption>
            {text}
          {text}
          <colgroup>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
            <col [width]>
          <tbody [id]>
        <p [class]>
```

No tags under the tbody tag.

By the way, what I wanted to get eventually was the contents of a href under td so that I can scrape the 6-digit stock codes.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend RSelenium for crawling java script website.(자바 스크립트로 된 사이트는 RSelenium으로 크롤링 하는게 좋습니다. 일반적인 html 파일과 다르게 반응형으로 되어 있기 때문이죠.)

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://finance.naver.com/sise/etf.nhn"
ch=wdman::chrome(port=4445L) #Set channel. If you have problem aboout chrome driver, please comment this answer.(크롬 드라이버로 문제가 생기면 코멘트를 달아주세요 답변해드릴게요)
remDr=remoteDriver(port=4445L, browserName='chrome')
remDr$open() #Open remote browser.
remDr$navigate(url) #Change browser to your web site.
source<-remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
main <- read_html(source)
dt <- main%>%html_table(fill = TRUE)

dt
[[1]]
                              종목명  현재가 전일비 등락률     NAV 3개월수익률     거래량 거래대금(백만) 시가총액(억) NA
1                                                NA                                                                   NA
2                          KODEX 200  25,540    175 +0.69%  25,557      -5.86%  3,033,694         77,550       57,810 NA
3                          TIGER 200  25,530    170 +0.67%  25,555      -5.82%  1,854,944         47,440       26,947 NA
4                     KODEX 레버리지  10,690    150 +1.42%  10,701     -12.45% 19,195,363        205,260       23,497 NA
5                     KODEX 단기채권 101,235      5  0.00% 101,231      +0.57%     35,383          3,581       13,738 NA
6                         KBSTAR 200  25,525    170 +0.67%  25,554      -5.88%    204,864          5,239       11,537 NA
7                                                NA                                                                   NA
8                                                NA                                                                   NA
9                                                NA                                                                   NA
10          KODEX 코스닥150 레버리지   6,125     40 -0.65%   6,160     -46.37% 33,056,841        203,228       11,276 NA
11     KODEX 종합채권(AA-이상)액티브 109,320    125 -0.11% 109,301      +3.30%     17,299          1,892       10,505 NA
12                    KODEX 삼성그룹   6,000     85 +1.44%   5,995      -4.38%     81,509            488        9,900 NA
13                       KODEX 200TR   8,015     60 +0.75%   8,014      -5.76%    611,115          4,900        9,245 NA
14                KODEX 단기채권PLUS 101,300     10 +0.01% 101,295      +0.60%      7,626            772        8,866 NA
15                                               NA                                                                   NA
16                                               NA                                                                   NA
17                                               NA                                                                   NA
18                  TIGER 단기통안채 101,085      5  0.00% 101,083      +0.43%     43,335          4,380        8,364 NA
19                        HANARO 200  25,550    180 +0.71%  25,566      -5.77%     63,381          1,621        7,780 NA
20               KODEX MSCI Korea TR   7,890    100 +1.28%   7,895      -5.45%    274,458          2,166        7,685 NA
21                       ARIRANG 200  25,645    175 +0.69%  25,659      -5.65%    311,488          8,002        7,411 NA
22                  KODEX Top5PlusTR  12,100    110 +0.92%  12,104      -4.12%      1,118             13        6,534 NA
23                                               NA                                                                   NA
24                                               NA                                                                   NA
25                                               NA                                                                   NA
26                         KOSEF 200  25,765    185 +0.72%  25,770      -5.86%    162,394          4,190        6,531 NA
27                        KINDEX 200  25,670    230 +0.90%  25,651      -5.73%    282,744          7,260        6,302 NA
28                  KODEX 코스닥 150   8,530     25 -0.29%   8,562     -25.47%  4,096,335         34,976        6,278 NA
29               TIGER MSCI Korea TR   9,820      0  0.00%   9,903      -5.82%          0              0        6,177 NA
30                      KODEX 코스피  19,495    245 +1.27%  19,486      -7.45%     39,984            779        5,166 NA
31                                               NA                                                                   NA
32                                               NA                                                                   NA
33                                               NA                                                                   NA
34                      KODEX 인버스   7,450     55 -0.73%   7,456      +6.50% 10,460,449         77,916        4,924 NA
35                       TIGER TOP10   7,930    115 +1.47%   7,904      -2.34%      3,182             25        4,865 NA
36                       SMART 200TR   8,340     70 +0.85%   8,331      -5.60%     18,004            150        4,566 NA
37              TIGER 단기채권액티브  50,590      0  0.00%  50,592      +0.47%      3,894            197        4,404 NA
38             KODEX 200선물인버스2X   8,515    115 -1.33%   8,521     +12.63% 17,984,754        152,854        4,283 NA
39                                               NA                                                                   NA
40                                               NA                                                                   NA
41                                               NA                                                                   NA
42            KODEX 선진국MSCI World  14,075    115 +0.82%     N/A      +2.55%      3,666             51        3,857 NA
43                  ARIRANG 고배당주  11,040      0  0.00%  11,030      -8.00%    145,379          1,607        3,580 NA
44                   TIGER 코스닥150   8,585     15 -0.17%   8,599     -25.33%    610,728          5,246        3,216 NA
45                       KOSEF 200TR  29,060    220 +0.76%  29,076      -5.91%      8,055            234        2,644 NA
46                     KBSTAR 코스피  19,520    200 +1.04%  19,483      -7.66%        767             14        2,372 NA
47                                               NA                                                                   NA
48                                               NA                                                                   NA
49                                               NA                                                                   NA
50                 KBSTAR 단기통안채 104,700     10 -0.01% 104,705      +0.54%        318             33        2,368 NA
51   TIGER 차이나CSI300레버리지(합..  17,010    440 -2.52%     N/A      -1.96%    101,746          1,761        2,347 NA
52                TIGER 차이나CSI300   8,325    115 -1.36%     N/A      +0.48%     99,383            834        2,264 NA
53             KBSTAR 대형고배당10TR   9,970     75 +0.76%   9,971      -4.04%        740              7        2,178 NA
54           KINDEX 베트남VN30(합성)  13,530     85 +0.63%     N/A      +3.56%    107,419          1,451        2,165 NA
55                                               NA                                                                   NA
56                                               NA                                                                   NA
57                                               NA                                                                   NA
58                      TIGER 200 IT  19,505    320 +1.67%  19,495      -3.46%     32,063            625        2,146 NA
59             KINDEX 중국본토CSI300  21,905     70 -0.32%     N/A      +1.25%     94,858          2,072        2,037 NA
60         KODEX 코스닥150선물인버스   9,555     40 +0.42%   9,567     +31.52% 29,789,385        284,731        1,901 NA
61                 KINDEX 단기통안채 101,220      0  0.00% 101,220      +0.48%     13,250          1,341        1,843 NA
62                      TIGER 코스피  19,495    180 +0.93%  19,490      -7.49%      6,102            119        1,794 NA
63                                               NA                                                                   NA
64                                               NA                                                                   NA
65                                               NA                                                                   NA
66                TIGER 중국소비테마   6,510      0  0.00%   6,515     -17.80%      7,005             45        1,791 NA
67  TIGER 글로벌4차산업혁신기술(합..  11,600    185 +1.62%     N/A      +1.89%     43,939            509        1,775 NA
68                  KBSTAR 코스닥150   8,445     25 -0.30%   8,464     -25.66%     12,069            101        1,579 NA
69                    KODEX 배당가치   9,540     60 +0.63%   9,538         N/A        329              3        1,498 NA
70                    TIGER 경기방어   9,195     70 +0.77%   9,193     -15.60%     19,365            178        1,416 NA
71                                               NA                                                                   NA
72                                               NA                                                                   NA
73                                               NA                                                                   NA
74    KODEX 단기변동금리부채권액티브 101,085     15 +0.01% 101,083      +0.41%      1,010            102        1,350 NA
75                          파워 200  25,970    175 +0.68%  25,984      -5.90%         50              1        1,273 NA
76             TIGER 200선물레버리지   8,040    115 +1.45%   8,039     -12.08%    273,474          2,200        1,118 NA
77                 HANARO 단기통안채 101,550      5  0.00% 101,550      +0.48%          3              0        1,080 NA
78           TIGER 미국S&P500선물(H)  34,445    360 +1.06%     N/A      +1.82%    141,474          4,865        1,076 NA
79                                               NA                                                                   NA
80                                               NA                                                                   NA
81                                               NA                                                                   NA
82                      KODEX KRX300  11,630     80 +0.69%  11,643      -7.70%     21,162            246        1,070 NA
83             TIGER 200선물인버스2X   8,625    165 -1.88%   8,660     +12.01%    983,282          8,500        1,052 NA
84      KBSTAR 코스닥150선물레버리지   5,965     45 -0.75%   5,963     -45.90%    156,885            939        1,041 NA
85                 KODEX 골드선물(H)  10,820     15 +0.14%     N/A     +16.47%    312,156          3,376        1,006 NA
86           KBSTAR 단기국공채액티브 101,615      5  0.00% 101,611      +0.80%    115,631         11,750          966 NA
87                                               NA                                                                   NA
88                                               NA                                                                   NA
89                                               NA                                                                   NA
90                   KODEX 국고채3년  57,155     60 -0.10%  57,151      +1.77%      2,832            161          960 NA
91                       TIGER 200TR  13,060    110 +0.85%  13,046      -6.21%          1              0          953 NA
92                  ARIRANG 코스피50  17,320    195 +1.14%  17,323      -4.36%     51,575            894          909 NA
93                   KOSEF 코스닥150   4,230      5 +0.12%   4,231     -25.98%        367              1          874 NA
94                    TIGER 헬스케어  23,610    390 +1.68%  23,700     -28.30%     46,091          1,085          869 NA
95                                               NA                                                                   NA
96                                               NA                                                                   NA
97                                               NA                                                                   NA
98                   KOSEF 통안채1년 102,430     10 -0.01% 102,432      +0.86%     40,879          4,187          850 NA
99             KBSTAR 중기우량회사채 105,455     65 -0.06% 105,428      +1.70%      2,136            225          844 NA
100         TIGER 코스닥150 레버리지   6,435     30 -0.46%   6,444     -46.42%  1,054,878          6,802          827 NA
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 596 rows ]
```

As you know, this website's table have spaces repeatably. You must do data cleansing processing.(알다시피, 해당 웹사이트 테이블에 공란이 존재합니다. 그래서 반복적으로 발생하는 na 값들을 삭제하는 작업을 수행하셔야 합니다.)

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me a very important clue. I encountered some problems with chromedriver version but I solved it after some searching. Many thanks!